# Get second level values from a json string

Tags: jquery, json

I'm building some `selectboxes` with some content from a JSON string. I was wondering how to get the second level from a string and pass it to the `selectboxes`. What I mean is this:

```
JSON
{
    "product": {
        options": {

            "58395": {
                "id": 58395,
                "title": "Maat",
                "values": {
                    "220544": {
                        "id": 220544,
                        "title": "36",
                        "active": true
                    },
                    "220545": {
                        "id": 220545,
                        "title": "37",
                        "active": false
                    },
                    "220546": {
                        "id": 220546,
                        "title": "38",
                        "active": false
                    },
                    "220547": {
                        "id": 220547,
                        "title": "39",
                        "active": false
                    }
                }
            },
            etc....
    }
}
```

My code

```
var $selectOptions = $('#wqs-select');
$.each(data.product.options, function (index, option){
    $selectOptions.append('<option value=' + option.id + '>' +option.value.title + '</option>');
});
```

So I need the title (eg. 36, 37, 38 or 39) inside the same option. So in place of `+option.value.title +` Do I need to do another `$.each`?? How do you do that?

Comment: Which title do you need for the product. There are 4 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a second $.each;

```
var $selectOptions = $('#wqs-select');
$.each(data.product.options, function (index, option){
    var ids = "";
    $.each(options.values, function (i, v) { ids += " " + v.id; });
    $selectOptions.append('<option value=' + option.id + '>' +option.value.title + ids + '</option>');
});
```